# Select where *every* record in join contains string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL tables:

`n_companies:`

```
id     company_name
1      Company A
2      Company B
```

`n_contacts:`

```
id     company_id     contact_name
1      1              John
2      1              Frank
3      2              Bobby
4      2              Sophie
```

`n_custom:`

```
id   custom_type   custom_type_id    gender   fav_colour
1    contacts      1                 male     red
2    contacts      2                 male     red
3    contacts      3                 male     red
4    contacts      4                 female   green
```

I am creating a search UI that allows people to search where any/every/no record contains a string.

This is the query I feel should be working for:

Find companies (`n_companies`) where every contact (`n_contacts`) is male (stored in a custom fields table `n_custom`):

```
SELECT 
    `n_companies`.`id`,
    `n_companies`.`company_name`
FROM `n_companies`
LEFT JOIN `n_contacts`
    ON ( `n_contacts`.`company_id` = `n_companies`.`id` )
LEFT JOIN `n_custom` AS `custom_contacts`
    ON ( `n_contacts`.`id` = `custom_contacts`.`custom_type_id`
    AND `custom_contacts`.`custom_type` = 'contacts' )
WHERE  
    EXISTS (
        SELECT `id`
        FROM   `n_custom`
        WHERE  `n_custom`.`custom_type_id` = `n_contacts`.`id` AND `n_custom`.`custom_type` = 'contacts'
        AND `n_custom`.`gender` LIKE '%male%'
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT `id`
        FROM   `n_custom`
        WHERE  `n_custom`.`custom_type_id` = `n_contacts`.`id` AND `n_custom`.`custom_type` = 'contacts'
        AND `n_custom`.`gender` NOT LIKE '%male%'
    )
GROUP BY
    `n_companies`.`id`
ORDER BY
    `n_companies`.`company_name` ASC
```

I am looking for the above query to only return `Company A` as both of its contacts are male.  `Company B` has 1 male and 1 female.

Notes:

- `n_companies` and `c_contacts` are tables created by default with
  standard fields.  `n_custom` is where users can create their own
  fields for storing information about various company-related tables.
- I can't do this search within the JOIN as there could be another `OR`
  search on `n_contacts` that is independent on the query above.

Can anyone help me with why my query isn't working?

Thank you in advance.

*EDIT*
I've just realised that my "no" record doesn't work either.  This in my mind should return zero rows, but it doesn't:

```
SELECT 
    `n_companies`.`id`,
    `n_companies`.`company_name`
FROM `n_companies`
LEFT JOIN `n_contacts`
    ON ( `n_contacts`.`company_id` = `n_companies`.`id` )
LEFT JOIN `n_custom` AS `custom_contacts`
    ON ( `n_contacts`.`id` = `custom_contacts`.`custom_type_id`
    AND `custom_contacts`.`custom_type` = 'contacts' )
WHERE  
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT `id`
        FROM   `n_custom`
        WHERE  `n_custom`.`custom_type_id` = `n_contacts`.`id` AND `n_custom`.`custom_type` = 'contacts'
        AND `n_custom`.`fav_colour` NOT LIKE '%red%'
    )
GROUP BY
    `n_companies`.`id`
ORDER BY
    `n_companies`.`company_name` ASC
```

Comment: relational division with no remainder.

Comment: The problem seems to be that `%male%` does also include `female`.

Comment: Agreed but if we change "male" to "red" and "female" to "green", it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for companies whose contacts match certain criteria. Aggregate your criteria per company and look at the results in the `HAVING` clause. An example:

```
select *
from companies
where id in
(
  select company_id
  from n_contacts con
  join n_custom cus on cus.custom_type_id = con.id and cus.custom_type = 'contacts'
  group by company_id
  having sum(cus.gender = 'male') = count(*) -- all contacts are male
     and sum(cus.fav_colour = 'red') = 2 -- at least two contacts like red
     and sum(cus.fav_colour = 'green') = 0 -- no contact likes green
     and sum(con.contact_name = 'John') > 0 -- at least one contact is named John
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query seems so complicated.  How about:

```
SELECT c.id, c.company_name
FROM n_companies c LEFT JOIN
     n_contacts co
     ON  co.company_id = c.id LEFT JOIN
     n_custom cu
     ON co.id = cu.custom_type_id AND
        cu.custom_type = 'contacts'
GROUP BY c.id, c.company_name
HAVING MIN(cu.gender) = 'male' AND MIN(cu.gender) = MAX(cu.gender);
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, that does work for my example but the problem is that I need the ability to search by multiple criteria and include and/or.  So in your query, I don't think I would be able to search for all contacts named "Sophie" *or* where everyone is male (which should return Company A *and* Company B...